# fread filling buffer with junk

Tags: c, linux, file, fread

I'm reading a file on linux and windows, on linux all work pretty well, but on windows, the `fread(r_hash, 1, 64 , f);` will put 64 char in r_hash then 32 char of junk, and I don't understand why. Here is my code Thanks!

```
int status;
FILE *f;
char *path;
char ln[64];
char *r_hash = calloc(64, 1);
path = malloc(1024);
path = strcpy(path, "some path");
status = -1;

f = fopen(path, "rb");

if (!f)
    return -1;

while (fscanf(f, "%s ", ln)!=EOF)
{
    fread(r_hash, 1, 64 , f);
    if(strcmp(w_hash, r_hash) == 0 && strcmp(hostname, ln) == 0)
    {
        status = 0;
        break;
    }
}

fclose(f);
```

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: something like :
`username someStringHashedAlways64CharLong`

Comment: I'm guessing there's no null character in the data you read from the file...

Comment: I can look for this, but even if there would be no null character at the end of the line, fread is supossed to read a max of 64 in this case

Comment: What does `fread()` return?  You're not checking the return value.

Comment: `fread()` reads *binary* data. It does not null-terminate the buffer, so calling `str*()` on the buffer is generally undefined.

Comment: `fread` does not add a terminating null byte to the data read.  `r_hash` has space for 64 bytes, and since you want a terminating null byte, you should read at most 63 bytes in your `fread` call.  Even then, you need to be prepared for a short read.  So, something like:

`size_t nread = fread(r_hash, 1, 63, f); if (nread > 0) r_hash[nread] = 0;` should work.  Optionally, look at `fgets` for reading data from text files.

Comment: fread return 64 as expected

Comment: You allocated 64 bytes for `r_hash`... you read 64 bytes from the file, into `r_hash`... you then use a string comparison function on it that expects a null to mark the end of the string.  If there wasn't one in that 64 bytes, it (`strcmp()`) keeps going past the end (unless it already mismatched by then)...

Comment: holy crap I was way to far into this problem to notice that I was only allocating 64 bytes... my problem is solved!

Comment: You still need to add a null byte to the data you've read by `fread`, even if you allocated memory for more than 64 bytes and are reading only 64 bytes in one `fread` call.

Comment: I know this is fixed already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r_hash = calloc(68, 1); // anything more than 64`

Comment: This will work only if you're sure to read the same number of bytes in each call to `fread`.  If any subsequent call reads fewer bytes, you will have "junk" left over from the previous call.  Try with a file where the second line has a hash that's smaller than 64 bytes in size and see what it prints :-).

Comment: Yes but I generate the file so reading it this ways is "safe" for my purpose